# Integrate Jenkins trend chart into dashing dashboard

Tags: ruby, jenkins, dashboard, dashing

We are running a Jenkins instance with various test jobs as part of the build chain.

I would like to integrate the build, test trend and general CI status information into graphs/widgets using the Shopify Dashing dashboard http://shopify.github.io/dashing/.

In other words, to have a standalone dashboard that indicates key info from the Jenkins instance.

Does anyone have experience with doing this kind of thing? Can you point me in the direction of any good resources/tutorials etc?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins' url structure is pretty rigid. For example, the build time trend graph for a project would be available at:

`http://<jenkinshost>:<port>/job/<jobname>/buildTimeGraph/png`

etc.  You should be able to just statically link to these using  tags in your HTML / ERB / templating language of your choice.

Other information is available via the remote access rest api, for e.g.

`http://<jenkinshost>:<port>/job/<jobname>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?pretty=true`

would give you a structure containing a lot of project metadata

Have a look at the documentation on the remote access API:  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: Thanks for this info @mcfinnigan, this looks promising.